# Does ios 16.5 support Web Push API from firebase?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, web-push

According to this page PUSH API will be supported from ios 16.
https://webkit.org/blog/12945/meet-web-push/

And According to this page ios 16.4 and 16.5 are partial support.
https://caniuse.com/push-api

Noted: Notification Permission has been allowed successfully

Now I've used this function to test if my phone is support Web Push or not

```
function WebPushSupported()
{   if (!window.Notification)
    {   return false;
    }
    
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator))
    {   return false;
    }
    
    if (!('PushManager' in window))
    {   return false;
    }   

    return true;
}
```

Now I've test on my ios 16.5 (13 pro max)
The result :

- For safari browswer : return false
- For PWA app : Return true

So on PWA app I can get token normally and when I try to use that token to send message then on results I got the message_id , but I still could not get notification on PWA app.

Here is my test request

[image]

Could you guy tell me Does push API is supported on ios PWA or not? If yes Do I miss some flows or settings for PWA app?

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with this too. I've read you must follow these steps:

1. Open Safari settings --> Experimental Features --> Push API

then,

1. Open the website your want permissions for in Safari
2. Share --> Add to Homescreen
3. Then open the app from your homescreen
4. Click your app's button to subscribe to push
5. Accept

When the user removes the app from the homescreen the permission is automatically revoked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, web push using FCM are supported in ios PWA. I have them working in my PWA.

Have you implemented a service worker to process the push notifications?

1. I suggest using [Google Worbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/) for the core of the service worker
2. Follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) to integrate FCM

Note: service worker are complex, and you will want to allocate some reasonable effort to get it properly working...

Comment: Would you mind share a bit more regarding this? I'm also trying to get FCM working with PWA on ios. But I can't even get FCM to work on ios, it keep throwing the following error when I try to send my vapid key with the `getToken` funcion.
`[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).`

I've enabled the `Push API` on my Safari mobile & desktop, but none of them be able to send the token to my server. Any suggestions would help, thank you in advanced.

Comment: @DannyWang What FCM version are you using?

Comment: ＠l1b3rty I'm currently testing with `firebase: ^9.22.2`

Answer (score -2):

I dont have the rep to upvote @SuperSecretAndNotSafeFromWork answer. But I can tell this was the solution for me.

I've been reading tons of forums and going into the experimental Features -> enable Push API then redownloading the application as a bookmark from Safari browser made the notifications works as expected with FCM!

Tested from FCM cloud test message UI in the firebase console. This is on iOS 16.4.1. Thank SuperSecretAndNotSafeFromWork for the answer :)

UPDATE: as of 16.5 (new phone) enable push API wasn't nessesary and it did work out of the box